# How to delete a string characters until first caps character (javascript/jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

If i have paragraphs like so:

```
<p class="text">ats hjda syd This is the story of a lost programmer and his doubts about javascript..</p>
```

Ho can I tell using javascript or jquery, to delete from all `p.text` the first characters until it meets a caps character ("T" in this case) ?
Even regex would be ok i guess.

The number of characters before the first caps letter are variable.

The first caps letter varies, is different for each paragraph.

I know how to code the version which delete characters until a character is met but never had to deal with a variable caps character case like this.

UPDATE: the alternative i've got to achieve what i need, is to count the third space, cause the caps letter comes after three words all the times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll('p');

paragraphs.forEach(paragraph => paragraph.innerText = paragraph.innerText.replace(/.*?([A-Z].*)/, (a,b)=>b));
```

```html
<p class="text">ats hjda syd This is the story of a lost programmer and his doubts about The language Javascript..</p>
```

Comment: Why not try 
`.*([A-Z].*)`
as regex?

Comment: @TonyR I am still learninf regex, so yeah thats a bit simpler, changed to that thanks.

Comment: I would extract the captured group ([A-Z].*)
This, in effect, deletes the string up to the first uppercase character.

Comment: @TonyR sorry not sure I understand that one. Maybe you can elaborate.

Comment: It kinda works, but if there are more caps letters in the paragraphs it deletes until last caps letter it finds. it should be the opposite, it should delete unitl the first it finds

Comment: sorry, fixed now!

Comment: This is the difference between the greedy quantifier and the lazy quantifier
Better would be [^A-Z]*([A-Z].*), because the lazy quantifier can be inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>



{
        let s = "<p class=ats hjda syd This is the story about javascript..</p>";
        let p = /.*([A-Z].*)/;
        let t = s.match(p);
        
        if (t != null) {// OK
            alert(t[1]); // extracted string
        }
        else alert('nok'); //no match
    }       
  </script>
```